# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency (GatsbyJs) with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, eslint, react-functional-component

I have a carousel in my component that i want to make slide independently when the component mounts,
so i use `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const carouselTimer = setInterval(() => {
      setPage(true);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(carouselTimer);
  }, []);
```

but the Gatsby ESLintError keeps throwing the warning.

```
warn ESLintError: 
/home/damiisdandy/Projects/Xxxxx/Xxxxxx-client/src/components/Header/Carousel/Carousel.jsx
  59:6  warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setPage'. Either include it or remove
the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

when i place the setPage in the dependency array i get another warning.

```
  23:9  warning  The 'setPage' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 59) change on
every render. To fix this, wrap the 'setPage' definition into its own useCallback() Hook
```

for more information on the setPage function, this is it.

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [flowDirection, setFlowDirection] = useState(true);

  const setPage = (direction) => {
    if (direction) {
      setFlowDirection(true);
      setCurrentPage((currentPage) => {
        if (currentPage === pages.length - 1) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return currentPage + 1;
        }
      });
    } else {
      setFlowDirection(false);
      setCurrentPage((currentPage) => {
        if (currentPage === 0) {
          return pages.length - 1;
        } else {
          return currentPage - 1;
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

i dont know how to handle this warning (i hate seeing warnings in my code), so how can i go about it. I just want to place a `setInterval` when the component mounts, and clear it when it unmounts..  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const setPage = React.useCallback((direction) => {
  if (direction) {
    setFlowDirection(true);
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => {
      if (currentPage === pages.length - 1) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return currentPage + 1;
      }
    });
  } else {
    setFlowDirection(false);
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => {
      if (currentPage === 0) {
        return pages.length - 1;
      } else {
        return currentPage - 1;
      }
    });
  }
}, [pages.length]);
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting

`warning  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'pages.length'. Either include it or
remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: add pages.length to the [] at the bottom, will update the code